# cloudant post bad request

Tags: javascript, json, post, cloudant

I am trying to post json objects into a cloudant database. Why am I receiving a "400 bad request" response?

```
pos = {
    'lat': position.coords.latitude,
    'long' : position.coords.longitude
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'http://03353b2e-7d68-462a-b0ab-d5feeae889fd-bluemix.cloudant.com/locations',
      data: pos,
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Comment: I guess because you try to post an object. Try this: `data: JSON.stringify(pos)`

Comment: Thanks Nico,

Just tried it and now I'm getting a 409 conflict error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually the 409 conflict was being caused by me trying to use the same ID multiple times. The stringify seems to have fixed it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by using

```
data: JSON.stringify(pos)
```

Thanks to Nico O for answer